# Using a table to loop from a SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

SparePart

| sparePartID | name | price | modelID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12V | Preheat Start Relay | 1470 | WADR40E |
| 12V. | Instrument Assembly | 1290 | WADR40E |
| 12V.. | Motor Module(360) | 17810 | WADR40E |
| 40CC | HST Assembly | 264840 | WADR40E |
| 4L88 | Oil Filter Core | 1200 | WADR40E |
| 4L88. | Diesel oil Filter Core | 260 | WADR40E |
| 4SB1490 | Belt | 9930 | WADR40E |
| 50*2.65 | Axeal -O Ring | 80 | WADR40E |
| 60*85*10 | Oil seal | 1180 | WADR40E |
| 9J-5-1605 | Joint Belt | 8960 | WADR40E |

and MainStock

| originalQty | qty | shipmentID | sparePartID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 20 | RnsttFOY | RT125-03001 |
| 10 | 10 | SHPMT78 | RT125-03001 |
| 8 | 8 | RH987ho | 12V |
| 0 | 0 | RH987ho | 4SB1490 |

So I use a query like this to count all stock from all shipments

```
SELECT SUM(`qty`) FROM MainStock WHERE sparePartID='RT125-03001';
```

I want to loop through each of sparePartID from SparePart table and get table results. I tried something like this.

```
SELECT SUM(`qty`)
    -> FROM MainStock, SparePart
    -> WHERE sparePartID=SparePart.sparePartID;
```

But I get a message saying

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'sparePartID' in where clause is ambiguous
```

So how can I accomplish this?

Comment: a sample of the desired result set would help

Comment: Do you want to list up all the sparePartID with its given sum('qty')?

Comment: The reason you're getting that message is because you aren't telling the query *which* table `sparePartID` is coming from (change it to `MainStock.SparePartID = SparePart.sparePartID`).  But that doesn't help you get to your expected result.  Can you show us what you expect the resultset to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need a loop, just a simple join and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SP.sparePartID, SUM(qty) as qty
FROM SparePart SP
LEFT JOIN MainStock MS
    ON SP.sparePartID = MS.sparePartID
GROUP BY SP.sparePartID
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add tables names to every column or better use aliases for your tables:

```
SELECT SUM(`qty`)
     FROM MainStock ms, SparePart sp
     WHERE ms.sparePartID=sp.sparePartID;
     Group by sp.sparePartID
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because, both table contains the column sparePartId. So lets give the table name also to avoid ambiguity .

```
SELECT Mainstock.sparePartId, SUM(`qty`) 
FROM MainStock, SparePart
WHERE Mainstock.sparePartID=SparePart.sparePartID;
```

Comment: This only solves his error, it doesn't answer his question.